# Selecting one form to be visible using jQuery

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery but have managed to get it working the way I want. The problem is, it's a bit convoluted and could easily get out of hand if I add more options.

I am trying to show and hide divs based on a user's dropdown selection. I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rchampniss/mdy7acwn/) with where I am so far, but I think it could do with some streamlining.

I'd like to be able to add five more dropdown options, with five more divs to show or hide. Will I need to hide each of them individually, or is there a way to say "if the div id is not the value selected, then hide it"?

I'm using CF7 to build the form.

```js
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "I have a query") {
            $("#cf-query").show("slow");
            $("#cf-booking").hide("slow")
        
        } else if ($(this).val() == "I would like to book") {
            $("#cf-booking").show("slow")
            $("#cf-query").hide("slow")

        } else {
            $(".cf-section").hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>What is the nature of your enquiry*:</h2>

<select id="cf-dd-nature">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="I have a query">I have a query</option>
    <option value="I would like to book">I would like to Book</option>
</select>

<div class="cf-section" id="cf-query" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Query</h2>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p>Surname*:</p>
    <p>Email Address*:</p>
    <p>Telephone number*:</p>
</div>


<div class="cf-section" id="cf-booking" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Booking</h2>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p>Telephone number*:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change the option values to the div ids

   ```
   <option value="cf-query">I have a query</option>
   …
   ```
2. Hide all elements with class `cf-section`.
3. Finally reference the value and show it, no need for the multiple if statements.

   ```
   $("select").change(function() {
     $(".cf-section").hide();
     id = "#" + $(this).val();
     $(id).show("slow");
   }
   ```

Now you can add as many as you want and your jQuery function code never changes.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but I still can't get this to work. Could you send a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skxygmeg/

Comment: Now this has been edited, it works.